# How to use torch.utils.tensorboard's SummaryWriter add_graph with dictionary outputs?

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, graph-visualization

I have a PyTorch model that inherits from `nn.Module` and that has a `forward` method which returns a dictionary containing multiple tensors (stored as values). When I try to log this model to TensorBoard using `torch.utils.tensorboard`'s `SummaryWriter.add_graph()` method I receive the following error:

`RuntimeError("Tracer cannot infer type of <output dictionary>`

How can I use `add_graph()` when the model's `forward()` method returns a dictionary?

Edit 1: Complete stack trace up to error:

```
WARNING:root:This caffe2 python run does not have GPU support. Will run in CPU only mode.
Only tensors or tuples of tensors can be output from traced functions (getOutput at /pytorch/torch/csrc/jit/tracer.cpp:208)
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string const&) + 0x33 (0x7fc661bd4273 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: torch::jit::tracer::TracingState::getOutput(c10::IValue const&) + 0x3e8 (0x7fc664cf77b8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
frame #2: torch::jit::tracer::exit(std::vector<c10::IValue, std::allocator<c10::IValue> > const&) + 0x3c (0x7fc664cf7aec in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
frame #3: <unknown function> + 0x47b0f2 (0x7fc66e4820f2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #4: <unknown function> + 0x48f061 (0x7fc66e496061 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #5: <unknown function> + 0x19da64 (0x7fc66e1a4a64 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #6: _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 0x35c (0x5674fc in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #7: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50abb3]
frame #8: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #9: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #10: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #11: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #12: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #13: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #14: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #15: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #16: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #17: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #18: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #19: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #20: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #21: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #22: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #23: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #24: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #25: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #26: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #27: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #28: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x1220 (0x50d390 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #29: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #30: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #31: _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 0x2e2 (0x509642 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #32: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x595311]
frame #33: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x54a6ff]
frame #34: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x551b81]
frame #35: _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 0x19c (0x5aa6ec in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #36: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50abb3]
frame #37: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x1220 (0x50d390 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #38: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #39: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x509d48]
frame #40: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #41: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #42: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #43: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #44: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x516915]
frame #45: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a8af]
frame #46: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #47: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #48: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #49: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #50: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #51: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #52: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #53: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x509d48]
frame #54: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #55: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #56: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #57: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #58: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #59: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #60: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x509d48]
frame #61: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #62: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #63: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]

Error occurs, No graph saved
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 42, in set_training
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/_pytorch_graph.py", line 234, in graph
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/_pytorch_graph.py", line 229, in graph
    trace = torch.jit.trace(model, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/jit/__init__.py", line 772, in trace
    check_tolerance, _force_outplace, _module_class)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/jit/__init__.py", line 904, in trace_module
    module._c._create_method_from_trace(method_name, func, example_inputs, var_lookup_fn, _force_outplace)
RuntimeError: Only tensors or tuples of tensors can be output from traced functions (getOutput at /pytorch/torch/csrc/jit/tracer.cpp:208)
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string const&) + 0x33 (0x7fc661bd4273 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: torch::jit::tracer::TracingState::getOutput(c10::IValue const&) + 0x3e8 (0x7fc664cf77b8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
frame #2: torch::jit::tracer::exit(std::vector<c10::IValue, std::allocator<c10::IValue> > const&) + 0x3c (0x7fc664cf7aec in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
frame #3: <unknown function> + 0x47b0f2 (0x7fc66e4820f2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #4: <unknown function> + 0x48f061 (0x7fc66e496061 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #5: <unknown function> + 0x19da64 (0x7fc66e1a4a64 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #6: _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 0x35c (0x5674fc in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #7: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50abb3]
frame #8: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #9: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #10: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #11: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #12: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #13: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #14: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #15: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #16: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #17: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #18: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #19: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #20: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #21: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #22: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #23: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #24: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #25: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #26: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #27: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #28: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x1220 (0x50d390 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #29: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #30: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #31: _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 0x2e2 (0x509642 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #32: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x595311]
frame #33: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x54a6ff]
frame #34: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x551b81]
frame #35: _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 0x19c (0x5aa6ec in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #36: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50abb3]
frame #37: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x1220 (0x50d390 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #38: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #39: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x509d48]
frame #40: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #41: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #42: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #43: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #44: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x516915]
frame #45: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a8af]
frame #46: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #47: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #48: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #49: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #50: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #51: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #52: <unknown function> + 0x18d10 (0x7fc6965ded10 in /home/rylan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/system/cythonExtensions/_pydevd_frame_eval_ext/pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #53: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x509d48]
frame #54: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #55: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #56: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
frame #57: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50a080]
frame #58: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #59: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #60: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x509d48]
frame #61: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x50aa7d]
frame #62: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 0x449 (0x50c5b9 in /usr/bin/python3.6)
frame #63: /usr/bin/python3.6() [0x508245]
```

Comment: I don't think it can be done as of now, but a full stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Added! I don't really see any useful information though. I can tell you that the error occurs at `torch/jit/__init__.py`'s line 904: `module._c._create_method_from_trace(method_name, func, example_inputs, var_lookup_fn, _force_outplace)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this model wrapper:

```
from collections import namedtuple
```

from typing import Any

class ModelWrapper(torch.nn.Module):
"""
Wrapper class for model with dict/list rvalues.
"""

```
def __init__(self, model: torch.nn.Module) -> None:
    """
    Init call.
    """
    super().__init__()
    self.model = model

def forward(self, input_x: torch.Tensor) -> Any:
    """
    Wrap forward call.
    """
    data = self.model(input_x)

    if isinstance(data, dict):
        data_named_tuple = namedtuple("ModelEndpoints", sorted(data.keys()))  # type: ignore
        data = data_named_tuple(**data)  # type: ignore

    elif isinstance(data, list):
        data = tuple(data)

    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is switching to `namedtuple` instead of `dict` (inspired by the other answer). For some reason you need to reinitialize it in the forward pass or the SummaryWriter gets confused.

Relevant code parts

```
from collections import namedtuple
Features = namedtuple('features', ['row', 'col', 'img')


class TabliterModel(nn.Module):
    ...
    def forward(self, features):
        # Convert tuple to namedtuple
        if type(features) == type((0,)):
            features = Features(**{field: features[i] for i, field in enumerate(Features._fields)})
        ...

        img_intermediate_values = self.layer_conv(features.image)
        ...

from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter("torchlogs/")
writer.add_graph(model, features)
writer.close()
```

Where features is an instance of the Features namedtuple. This allows you to use attribute based item getting (e.g. `features.image` instead of the bug-inviting `features[2]`) while retaining the `add_graph()` functionality of `tensorboard`.